# Bootstrap 5 container class leaving blank space, even without margins

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-5

I'm working on something kind of simple:

I have a div, that inside has two divs side by side. On the left there's a map and on the right there's some text. Both are hidden by default (`display: none`) and are shown on button click. I'm getting this at the moment:

[image]

And my idea would be to be able to use at least some of the blank space on the right. By my calculations width is getting topped at 70% (1320px), anything above that doesn't change the layout.

This is the relevant html:

```
<div class="container">


<div id="graph"  class="map-placeholder"></div>


<div style="display: {{ params.display }}" id="texto-apoyo-app" class="lead text texto-app ">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis molestie vitae lacus id consectetur. Sed lacus purus, iaculis vitae enim sit amet, vulputate cursus ipsum. Donec sed finibus velit. Suspendisse iaculis sapien vitae iaculis laoreet. Donec ut facilisis nisl, ac condimentum enim. Proin mattis quam lacinia mi laoreet suscipit. Nulla facilisis massa turpis, sit amet suscipit diam convallis a. Nulla ut turpis at augue aliquam fringilla at eget felis.

</div>
</div>
```

And this is the relevant .css (other than default boostrap 5 classes):

```
    .container {


        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row; /* On desktop, the text will be beside the plot */
    }

.map-placeholder {
        width: 60%; 
        height: 600px; 
        margin-top: 10px; 


    }


    .texto-app{

        width: 35%;
    }
```

Any idea what am I missing? I'm using Flask and Plotly, too, if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap, why not just ```cols```? This would mean something like - give 'map-placeholder' a size of col-lg-7, and 'text-to-app' a size of col-lg-4. You're then left with col-lg-1 which would be extra space (this would be the equivalent of the 5% space you have left using your current design)